# How to obtain a pdf of a random variable defined as a function of many variables?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Given $N$ independent random variables ($X_1$,$X_2$,...,$X_N$) with individual pdfs $f_1$,...,$f_N$:

How to determine the pdf of a random variable $Y=G(X_1,...,X_N)$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the CDF would be
$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]
 = \int_{A_y} \prod_{k=1}^N f_k(x_k) dx_1 \ldots dx_N,
$$
where $A_y$ is the region of $\mathbb R^N$  where $G(x_1, \ldots, x_N) \leq y$
and the pdf is given by
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{dF_Y(y)}{dy}.
$$

Comment: @Did thanks for the edit