# Difficult multivarate random variable - how to calculate it?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I have a random variable defined by $Y=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N}l_j \cos\theta_j}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}l_j\sin\theta_j}$ where $l_j \sim \text{log-normal-distribution} (\left \langle l \right \rangle, \sigma _l)$ for all $j$ and $\theta_j \sim \text{normal-distribution} (0, \sigma _\theta)$ for all $j$.

Following the post [How to obtain a pdf of a random variable defined as a function of many variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624958/how-to-obtain-a-pdf-of-a-random-variable-defined-as-a-function-of-many-variables/)

How can I obtain a explicit expression for $f_Y(y)$? I'm really stuck with the math involved in this problem. 
In the case that an explicit expression can not be obtained:

1) I must demostrate that an explicit expression can not be obtained

2) Can I aproximate this function $f_Y(y)$ in some way?

Waiting for your answers.

Thanks a lot!!

Best regards.

Comment: Maybe one can write $l_j=e^{n_j}$ so that $n_j$ is normally distributed and write $z_j = e^{n_j+i \theta_j}=e^{w_j}$ so $w_j$ is bivariate normal. Then $Y=Re(\sum z_j)/Im (\sum z_j)$...

Comment: Thanks! I dont know what must I do next. Can somebody help? Thanks a lot